# Ошибка при сборке apk файла python kivy buildozer

Tags: python

При компиляции buildozer android debug deploy run появляется такая ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста. Код файла простое приложение с картинками. Компилирую на виртуальной машине - ubuntu 18.04.6

## Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--

```
dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '-- 
arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage- 
dir=/home/nikita/game/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk- 
api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#   CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#   LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#   LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#   XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#   LANG = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#   MANAGERPID = '913'
#   DISPLAY = ':0'
#   INVOCATION_ID = '52a42bb8371647adbaa5e92839d44b63'
#   GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#   COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#   USERNAME = 'nikita'
#   XDG_VTNR = '1'
#   SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#   XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
#   USER = 'nikita'
#   DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#   QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#   TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#   GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/59250e57_aca5_417b_99f4_656fb78a816a'
#   PWD = '/home/nikita/game'
#   HOME = '/home/nikita'
#   JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:23265'
#   TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#   SSH_AGENT_PID = '1067'
#   QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#   XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#   XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#   XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#   DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=4f6c16e640772503498f5604654f75fa'
#   GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#   WINDOWPATH = '1'
#   TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#   SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#   VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#   QT_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#   XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#   IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#   DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#   XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#   GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#   GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.77'
#   XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#   SHLVL = '1'
#   GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#   GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#   LOGNAME = 'nikita'
#   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=4f6c16e640772503498f5604654f75fa'
#   XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#   XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#   XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#   PATH = '/home/nikita/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/nikita/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#   SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/nikita-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/972,unix/nikita-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/972'
#   LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#   GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#   _ = '/home/nikita/.local/bin/buildozer'
#   PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/nikita/.buildozer/android/packages'
#   ANDROIDSDK = '/home/nikita/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#   ANDROIDNDK = '/home/nikita/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#   ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#   ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: собственно ошибки-то у вас и не приведено. последуйте инструкциям, которые вы же сами и привели, в последних строках.